# Necklace combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

If $n$ is the number of necklaces which can be formed using $17$ identical pearls and two identical diamonds and similarly $m$ is the number of necklaces which can be formed using $17$ identical pearls and $2$ different diamonds, then the value of $m$ and $n$ is?

Comment: What have you done so far? Where are you stuck? Can you figure out the problem if $17$ was a smaller number like $3$ or $4$, for example? Try to extend that logic.

Comment: Well I am not sure how to start

Comment: In both questions, it is about where to  place the diamonds. For example, let us call the diamonds $D$ (for the first question, where they are the same). Draw the skeleton of a necklace, and find out in how many ways can you place the two diamonds. The pearls will have to go in the other places, right?

Comment: Very good. In how many ways can you select two places? Remember, we are talking about places in a *necklace*, which loops back into itself, so only the distance between the two diamonds matters.

Answer (score 0):

Use Burnside's Lemma.

> If $G$ is a finite group of permutations on a set $S$, then the number of orbits of $G$ on $S$ is
>   \begin{align}
> \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}|\operatorname{fix}(g)|.
> \end{align}

Observe there are $\binom{19}{2}=171$ possible designs (of course, some of them are equivalent by rotation and reflection). Let $G = D_{38}$ act on the $171$ necklace designs. Observe we see that
\begin{matrix}
\text{element} & \text{Number of Designs Fixed by Element}\\
e & 171\\
r^k, k=1,\ldots, 18 & 0\\
f & 9\\
fr^k, k=1,\ldots, 18 & 9
\end{matrix}
Hence by Burnside's lemma, we see that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{38}(171+9+9*18) = 9.
\end{align}

Indeed, one possible configuration is that the two diamonds are $1$ apart on one side and $16$ apart on the other side or $3$ apart on one side and $14$ apart on the other side...until $17$ apart on one side and $0$ apart on the other side. Hence $9$ configurations.

Comment: Isn't this overkill...

Comment: @YiFan Yes. But my last paragraph gives a simple proof.

Comment: I don't know this Theorem, can you tell any other method. Thanks